# FREEBASE Music Artist explorer

Tags: freebase

I am trying to retrieve all the interesting details related to a music artist from within FREEBASE.

The details i desire are (for any particular artist, e.g. "The Police") is:-

a). Each and every ALBUM they have released.
b). for each ALBUM get engineer, producer, catalog number, date and country of release
c). For each ALBUM Released, get all Tracks
d). for each track, get duration, lyrics, youtube video

I have developed this MQL query so far which does give me a lot of what i desire

```
[{
  "type": "/music/artist",
  "name": "The Police",
  "album": [{
    "name": null,
    "genre": [],
    "releases": [{
      "*": null,
      "track": [{}]
    }]
  }]
}]
```

however, i cannot retrieve the track duration
i have found FREEBASE used to link to LyricWkiki for lyrics so i can investigate that further to obtain (1/7th) of the lyrcis

my questions are

does FREEBASE hold youtube video links for ALBUM tracks? and if it does, how do i retrieve these links?

what do i need to add to my MQL query to get ALBUM art work?
Does FREEBASE have the album sleeve notes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might have to wait for Freebase to catch up to you.  Or,... you could go through and edit the incomplete [keys](https://www.freebase.com/m/01hmsw9?keys=) to create the links you are looking for, then you could use them to query for the data. I'm sure Google would appreciate that.  Even a [topic search](https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic//m/01hmsw9) on an album brings up no track names, (let alone duration).  Another possibility is to query directly to YouTube through their [API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/). That's assuming you get the track names.  Keep us posted, I would like to know how this turns out.

(I know this is not the answer you are looking for, but it did not fit in a comment.)